# How to retrieve supported TLS version and supported ciphers for a CN using python

Tags: python, ssl

I'm getting the result as only the latest supported TLS version(TLS 1.3), I want to print all supported TLS version like TLs 1.2, TLS 1.1 etc

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, ssl, socket
    from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
    import json
    #some site without http/https in the path
    base_url = 'google.com'
    port = '443'`enter code here`
    
    hostname = base_url
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    
    with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
            print(ssock.version())
            data = json.dumps(ssock.getpeercert())
            
    
    #print (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

A TLS client cannot query the server for what it supports. A TLS client can only make an offer regarding ciphers, TLS versions, curves etc and then try to do a SSL handshake with the server by using this offer. If it succeeds then the server supports this particular combination.

But this also means that the TLS client must support this particular combination also in the first place. For example if the server still supports RC4 ciphers (insecure) but the client TLS stack does not support it, then the SSL handshake will fail also - if the TLS stack allows a handshake start with an unsupported cipher in the first place. And most modern TLS stacks actually have such insecure ciphers disabled or they are often not even compiled in any more, which means one would need to use its own TLS library compiled with support for the older ciphers and TLS versions.

Thus, you can iterate over all TLS versions and create a new context with this specific TLS version - see [ssl.SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) which has a `protocol` parameter.

Then you need to also set the specific ciphers you want to test with [set_ciphers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers) on this context. For the name of these ciphers and how to specify them see [openssl ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html) and you can run `openssl ciphers -V` also to check which ciphers are compiled into your particular version  of openssl. Note also that not all ciphers can be combined with all TLS protocol versions,  but this is also documented.

If a TLS handshake is successful you know at least that this particular combination is supported. If it fails then it will not mean in all cases that it is not supported since there might also be handshake problems due to weak DH keys, unsupported curves, server requiring a client certificate etc ... i.e. your task is far from trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how i have fixed.

First get the supported ciphers. You need openssl installed

```
    def load_ciphers(self):
    try:
        output = subprocess.run(["openssl", "ciphers"], capture_output=True).stdout
        output_str = output.decode("utf-8")
        ciphers = output_str.strip().split("\n")
        return ciphers[0]
    except:
        return ""
```

And use the following to set the ciphers

```
    ciphers = load_ciphers()
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
    context.set_ciphers(ciphers)
```

That worked for me. Hope this helps.